# Valores calculados no Javascript não aparecem com casas decimais

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho feito esse cálculo, que está funcionando perfeitamente.
O problema que está ocorrendo é que quando retorna os valores para a tela (View) retorna sem as casas decimais calculadas.

Vou demonstrar o que está ocorrendo.
Este é meu JavaScript:

```
var QtdeDiasJuros = $("#T_FrmRecTotalDiaAtraso").val();
var TaxaJurosAoDia = $("#T_FrmRecTaxaJurosAoDia").val().replace(",", ".");
var ValorParcela = $("#T_FrmRecValorDuplicata").val();
var TotalJurosAoDia = parseFloat(QtdeDiasJuros) * parseFloat(TaxaJurosAoDia);
var TotalValorPago = (parseFloat(TotalJurosAoDia) + parseFloat(ValorParcela));

document.getElementById("T_FrmRecTotalJurosAoDia").value = TotalJurosAoDia;
document.getElementById("T_FrmRecValorPago").value = parseFloat(TotalValorPago);
```

Processo do Calculo e seus resultado:
Exemplificando o Calculo com lançamento dos valores:

```
var QtdeDiasJuros = $("#T_FrmRecTotalDiaAtraso").val();
10
var TaxaJurosAoDia = $("#T_FrmRecTaxaJurosAoDia").val().replace(",", ".");
0,333
var ValorParcela = $("#T_FrmRecValorDuplicata").val();
100,50
var TotalJurosAoDia = parseFloat(QtdeDiasJuros) * parseFloat(TaxaJurosAoDia);
3,33
var TotalValorPago = (parseFloat(TotalJurosAoDia) + parseFloat(ValorParcela));
                               103,83  =                            3,33              +     100,50
```

O problema é que quando retorna para a tela retorna valores sem a casa decimal e não posicionando conforme o calculo gerou.
tipo:   TotalValorPago fica 10333,00   - TotalJurosAoDia fica: 333,00

Aqui minha View:
Aqui esta os campos onde recebe estes valores gerados pelo JavaScript

```
<div class="span2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTaxaJurosAoDia)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTaxaJurosAoDia, new { style = "width: 80px; font-weight: bold;  font-size: 18px; color: #39395F; background-color:#E0E0E0 ;  text-align: right;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTaxaJurosAoDia)
</div>

<div class="span2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTotalDiaAtraso)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTotalDiaAtraso, new { style = "width: 100px; font-weight: bold;  font-size: 18px; color: #39395F; background-color:#E0E0E0 ;  text-align: right;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTotalDiaAtraso)
</div>

<div class="span2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTotalJurosAoDia)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmRecTotalJurosAoDia, new { style = "width: 100px; font-weight: bold;  font-size: 18px; color: #39395F; background-color:#E0E0E0 ;  text-align: right;" })
</div>

<div class="span2">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.T_FrmRecValorPago, new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.T_FrmRecValorPago, new { style = "width: 200px; font-size: 20px; color: #F2F2F4; background-color:#39395F; text-align: right;" })
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrg Pablo, pela correção, vou me atentar melhor, grato

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema das casas decimais, dessa maneira:

```
document.getElementById("T_FrmRecTotalJurosAoDia").value = parseFloat(TotalJurosAoDia).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
                document.getElementById("T_FrmRecValorPago").value = parseFloat(TotalValorPago).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
```

Espero que possa ajudar a quem possa vir a ter esta mesma dúvida.